# Tomcat 7.0+ How to launch with a custom ApplicationContext

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

I'm trying to figure out a way to ask Tomcat(**nicely**) to launch the server with my custom ApplicationContext for example:

```
public class MyApplicationContext 
             extends ApplicationContext {

      ...  (Some BL)  ...
}
```

Is there an xml parameter I can override somewhere so it would load my class and not the default one?

Comment: ApplicationContext sounds like Spring Framework. What are you trying to do with that context? Do you want to execute bl when your application starts up?

Comment: I want to be able to access some Java BL from my JSPs... its more complicated than just that, but this is one of the things I would like to do.

Comment: So you are using Spring Framework and Spring MVC or plain JSP?

Comment: Plain Tomcat... nothing else

Comment: @Stefan Thank you for reminding me about the ContextListener... I completely forgot about that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my solution to the issue is to add a ContextListener, and in it initialize a "singleton" that later would be accessed from the servlets. -- I'm still testing this one.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat's [configuration documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html) says that the <Context> configuration node accepts a "className" attribute, about which it says,

> "Java class name of the implementation to use. This class must
>   implement the org.apache.catalina.Context interface. If not specified,
>   the standard value (defined below) will be used."

Comment: I see you point, it is like a servlet class name, that creates a servlet type as a context. I was searching for a more general solution where all the Context of the Tomcat would share the same type. and I'm afraid that is impossible without taking tomcat apart :)